Google Earth Engine: Layer becomes blurry after zooming in
Using Google Earth Engine, is it possible that when I zoom in on a layer, it becomes blurry? Is this due to insufficient clarity of the layer itself or is it due to a free account?

What software are you using? Free account of what?

Google Earth Engine
